# Enabling Anti-aliasing for an iOS game

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, opengl-es, antialiasing

I am developing a 3D game for iPhone and iPad without using any game engine. I have found that the edges of the 3D elements are jagged. After research I understood that to fix this issue I need to enable anti-aliasing in iOS. I have followed this (https://nicolasgoles.com/blog/2010/07/tutorial-using-anti-aliasing-msaa-in-the-iphone/) article to enable anti-aliasing using concept of multisampling. Even after using this approach some of the edges are still jagged. I have tried increasing sample count with this approach, but there was no improvement. I have the following questions:

1. Are there any other methods which can provide better output compared to multisampling approach?
2. Any improvement required in the current approach?
3. I have seen many 3D games on iOS with high quality of anti-aliasing. What type of anti-aliasing method is used by these games?

I’d appreciate any suggestions on this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The multisampling with 4 samples should work good enough even on non retina devices. On retina devices you should have trouble seeing jagged elements even without the multisampling enabled. So to begin with please check what is your frame buffer size as you do need to set the scale on the layer to get the appropriate size and if that is set to 1 you will display a non retina buffer on a retina device.

Comment: Thank you very much @MaticOblak for your suggestions/guidance. I increased the frame buffer size for retina display to fix this issue. I was able to enable anti-aliasing for iPhone and iPad, but at the cost of performance.

Comment: Yes, the antialiasing will cost you some performance but the buffer size increase will as well. Understand there are 4 times more fragments for a scale of 2.0 and 9 times more fragments for the scale of 3.0.